# Using proxy in playwright python

Tags: python, networking, proxy, playwright

I'm not sure how proxy is used but I tried something and failed. I got proxy list from this site >> https://www.freeproxylists.net/ After reading the playwright documentation, I feel like this should be the code to connect to free proxy server 203.176.179.255 running on port 8080 and HTTP protocol :

```
from playwright.sync_api import sync_playwright
def run(playwright):
    chromium = playwright.chromium 
    browser = chromium.launch(channel='chrome',headless=False,proxy={"server":"http://203.176.179.255:8080"})
    page = browser.new_page()
    page.goto("https://grabify.link/4R47U5")


with sync_playwright() as playwright:
    run(playwright)
```

I got this error and I can't understand what is the problem. I don't know how proxy is used, I did read some articles but none of them helped. Yes, they made me understand what proxy is but none of them helped me with this one.

```
File "C:/Users/NNB-Suppliers/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python37/playwright test.py", line 12, in <module>
run(playwright)
File "C:/Users/NNB-Suppliers/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python37/playwright test.py", line 8, in run
page.goto("https://grabify.link/4R47U5")
File "C:\Users\NNB-Suppliers\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\playwright\sync_api\_generated.py", line 7432, in goto
url=url, timeout=timeout, waitUntil=wait_until, referer=referer
File "C:\Users\NNB-Suppliers\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\playwright\_impl\_sync_base.py", line 104, in _sync
return task.result()
File "C:\Users\NNB-Suppliers\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\playwright\_impl\_page.py", line 494, in goto
return await self._main_frame.goto(**locals_to_params(locals()))
File "C:\Users\NNB-Suppliers\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\playwright\_impl\_frame.py", line 136, in goto
await self._channel.send("goto", locals_to_params(locals()))
File "C:\Users\NNB-Suppliers\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\playwright\_impl\_connection.py", line 44, in send
lambda: self.inner_send(method, params, False)
File "C:\Users\NNB-Suppliers\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\playwright\_impl\_connection.py", line 387, in wrap_api_call
return await cb()
File "C:\Users\NNB-Suppliers\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\playwright\_impl\_connection.py", line 78, in inner_send
result = next(iter(done)).result()
playwright._impl._api_types.Error: net::ERR_TIMED_OUT at https://grabify.link/4R47U5
=========================== logs ===========================
navigating to "https://grabify.link/4R47U5", waiting until "load"
============================================================
```

Comment: It says it timed out, probably because the proxy was free (and thus slow/dead).

Comment: @CharchitAgarwal but my process of using proxy is right?

Comment: @CharchitAgarwal how can I make it work, how can i make it wait until pageload

Comment: By default it waits for 30s, so if it doesn't load by then, then the proxy is probably dead. Try switching to a paid, better quality one. But you can increase the time it waits by specifying `timeout` (in ms) in `page.goto`

Comment: Would you mind helping me with waiting time, i tired some code but they didn't work.

Comment: `page.goto("https://grabify.link/4R47U5", timeout=60000) # Waits 60s` or alternatively, to disable timeout completely use `page.goto("https://grabify.link/4R47U5", timeout=0)`

Comment: Did you clarify the issue? I have exactly the same problem. tx (am aware about bad px)

Comment: This code works perfectly just I was using a bad proxy server.

Comment: I used a paid and working ISP proxy and got the same problem. Does python playwright support authenticated proxy integrations?

Comment: @Andrea after using different proxies, everything was working well.

Answer (score 0):

`browser = chromium.launch(proxy={ "server": "http://myproxy.com:3128", "username": "usr", "password": "pwd" })`

you can use this as documentation in [Playwright Newwork](https://playwright.dev/python/docs/network)